# How to clear out the field value of picklist field using LexiLoader or Data Loader

Tags: data-loader, bulk

I have a large number of records that I need to clear out the piccoloist values of a field for. I have the ID's of the records and I would like to use a Data Loader to clear out the fields based on the ID's. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible you just need to check the 'Insert null values' option in DataLoader / LexiLoader.

[link](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005442)

> Description How can you update records with Blank values using Data Loader?
>
> Resolution There is a setting in Data Loader that allows for updating
>   a field with a NULL value where values exist.
>
> To allow Null values to be included in an update:
>   1.  Launch Data Loader
>   2.  Select Settings
>   3.  Check box - Insert Null Values.
>
> Operational Sample:
>   1.  Run Export Data - include id, Column Field(s) that should be changed to blank.  (Make sure to keep the original export file as your
>   data backup)
>   2.  Delete data contained in column(s) that should be returned as NULL (no values).
>   3.  Save new .csv with new name to avoid overwriting Data Export in Step 1 of this sample process.
>   4.  Run Data Loader Update using new file with Blank values.